# A strange condition of convexity?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, inequalities

During my research, I come across this question.

Let $f \in C^2(\mathbb R, \mathbb R_+^*)$ with $\forall x \in\mathbb R, f'(x) \geq |f''(x)+f(x)|$.

> Is it true that $\forall x \in \mathbb R, f''(x) \geq 0$ ?

Comment: What is $\mathbb R_+^*$?

Comment: $\mathbb R_+^*=] 0,+\infty[$

Comment: I don't think it can be true, because for instance one may modify exp(2x)  locally at 0, making $f''<0$ without affecting the inequality

Comment: @PietroMajer: It's not purely a local question though (near $x=0$, $f(x)=\sin x$ also works fine as a counterexample), and in any event, $f(x)=e^{2x}$ doesn't satisfy the inequality.

Comment: @PietroMajer: I think the question has more content than you gave it credit for. Let's say we indeed try $f(x)=\sin x$, lazily until the maximum $x=\pi/2$. But now we're doomed, we can't continue past this point because we can no longer afford $f''<0$ (this would make $f'$ negative), so must make $f'\ge 1$ and thus can't keep the function $C^2$.

Comment: @Dattier : It's not $\mathbb R_+^*=]0,+\infty[;$ rather, it is $\mathbb R_+^*=\mathopen]0,+\infty\mathclose[.$ The conspicuous lack of proper horizontal spacing in the former is the result of MathJax treating the `]` character as a right delimiter rather than as a left delimiter. I coded the latter as `\mathbb R_+^*\mathopen]0,+\infty\mathclose[`, but it can also be coded as `\mathbb R_+^*\left]0,+\infty\right[``. The latter way of coding it also in some cases affects sizes of the delimiters.

Comment: $$ \begin{align} \text{right: } \quad & \mathbb R_+^* = \mathopen]0,+\infty\mathclose[ \\ {} \\ \text{wrong: } \quad & \mathbb R_+^* = ]0,+\infty[ \end{align} $$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such function.

In terms of $g=f'/f$, the inequality becomes $g\ge |1+g^2+g'|$ or $|g'/g+g+1/g|\le 1$, at least when $g>0$. This shows that $g'/g\le -1$ or $g'\le -g$, and this last conclusion is clearly also correct when $g=0$.

Gronwall's inequality now shows that $g(x)\le ae^{-x}$. Since $g=(\log f)'$ and this bound is integrable on $x>0$, it follows that $f$ is bounded.

Since $f$ is also increasing, $L=\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists, and $f'(x)\to 0$. However, then the inequality forces $f''(x)\to -L$, which will make $f'$ negative eventually, leading to a contradiction.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: I was indeed a bit sloppy at the end, but everything is fine as written anyway: $g=f'/f\le ae^{-x}$, so $f'$ does go to zero. Even if it didn't, we still have $f'\in L^1$ from $f\to L$, so $f''+f\in L^1$, and then integrating we obtain $f'(x)=-Lx + o(x)$, which is good enough.

Comment: In fact, it would have been slightly easier to not go back to $f$ at all: $g(x)\to 0$, so $g'\to -1$, which would make $g$ negative eventually, but clearly $g\ge 0$ under our assumptions on $f$.